# How to add app to crashlytics without using plugin for ide?

Tags: crashlytics

Plug-in for the Android Studio (latest) does not start (crash).
How to add app to crashlytics without using plugin for ide?

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics here. What error are you seeing?

Comment: Hi! It works now! Probably bug report helped to correct the error. Thanks!